# How to add something to the android keyboard?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyboard

I'm looking for the simplest solution:
- I want to add a button to the android keyboard that can interact with a service I run in the background
- So when the button is pressed it can send "hi" to my service

How can I add something to the keyboard, that when pressed, will tell my application that it was pressed?  I'm thinking maybe put it in as a new language(emoji style)? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: really it's an interesting question, i hope someone can answer to it, i will keep watching for this question (y)

Comment: It might helpful to you: https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/FBZrVnbUCXZ

Comment: thank you all, actually I think I will just go with a floating button like chat head, seems better for my needs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify Android keyboard like you have no rights to modify other apps. You can do is create a keyboard app.